# No resource found that matches the given name at label

Tags: java, android, manifest

I just wanted to change the Icon and the name of my application. I changed in the strings.xml file the "app_name".

```
<string name="app_name">Linak</string>
```

But since i clicked on this line in the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/linak120x120"
    android:label="@string/Linak"     <-----this line
```

nothing works anymore.

The error message is :
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/Linak').

Even when I want to delete or Undo this line the error appears.

Comment: I think you need to reference the string variable, not the string value, like so: `android:label="@string/app_name"`.

Comment: I did you suppose but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: I tryied this allready. But when I click on Run Android Studio gives an error and writes again  android:label="@string/Linak" over android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: clean the project and delete the line  <string name="app_name">Linak</string>   then write again

Comment: I can write what ever I want Android Studio jumps into the AndroidManifest.xml file and highlights this line:  android:label="@string/Linak" and on the top is this message:Files under build folder are generated and should not be edited.

Comment: Did you try to write  android:label="Linak"   you should not take an error i think but not a good solution.

Comment: Yes I did. But when I click on run it writes android:label="@string/Linak" again

Comment: restart the studio then clean the project. There can be a bug. if not solved create a new manifest file and delete old one.

Comment: Now it`s fixed. I don`t know how but I tryied everything with android:label="@string/app_name" and then suddenly it build with success

Answer (score 1):

Confirm you are editing the *real* AndroidManifest.xml as declared by your sourceSets - example: android.sourceSets.main { manifest.srcFile 'src/somePath/AndroidManifest.xml' }

Double clicking the build error will often take you to the *generated* AndroidManifest.xml gradle creates from the manifest merge processing based on buildType, flavor, and other tasks.

(If mouse over the tab in Android Studio it will show the path to the manifest. The generated manifest is in build/intermediates/... and overwritten by merge result)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. If you locate the physical file -> should be in Properties subfolder and open the xml file in Notepadd++ you can then edit the line permanently. I replicated the edit in Visual Studio and this time I was able to save and it didn't revert to the default.

Hope this helps!